# Index method not accepting parameters in ASP.NET Core MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a webpage where I have to filter results using value from the select menu's selected option when the user clicks on filter button by sending a get parameter to the index method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `refId` is never passed into the `Index` method

In your code, we can find that you specify `asp-for="@Model.FirstOrDefault().RefereeId"` for your `<select>` tag, if you check the source code of this dropdown in browser, you would find **`name` attribute** value is `RefereeId` (not `refId`) as below. So it would pass something like `RefereeId=168` through querystring to your action, and parameter `refId` of your action would always be 0, which cause the issue.

[image]

To fix it, you can try to rename your action parameter to `RefereeId`, like below.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int RefereeId)
{
    //code logic here
```

Or modify view page code to set name of `<select>` tag with "**refId**".

```
<select name="refId" asp-items="@ViewBag.PersonId"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a custom route defined, the default routing in asp.net core uses `id`.

Replace the `refId` parameter to `id`.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id)
{
    // ...

    if (id != 0) //always remains 0
    {
        games = games.Where(g => g.RefereeId == id);
    }

    // ...
}
```